# Restoring a .bz2 Mysql Backup?

Tags: backup, mysql, restore

I've tried doing my research on this, found this website: http://www.lullabot.com/blog/importexport-large-mysql-databases and still am confused as to why this isn't working like it should. I'm trying to restore a mysql .bz2 backup from one server to another with the database. The command I'm running to do so is:

```
 bunzip2 SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_live-2012-01-05.sql.bz2 | mysql -h 192.168.255.53 -u sobuser -p summaries_criticaltest
```

I'm running this in a folder of 2 backup files being:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19339638 Jan  5 13:50 SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_dev-2012-01-05.sql.bz2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      453 Jan 10 09:45 SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_live-2012-01-05.sql.bz2
```

The output I'm getting is just this: bunzip2: Output file SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_live-2012-01-05.sql already exists.

I'm not trying to dump anything, just restore the backup zip to the database. I may be doing this all wrong but any help would be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first command will decompress SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_live-2012-01-05.sql.bz2 to SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_live-2012-01-05.sql - and apparently that already happened once.

From `man bunzip2` (at your box, or online e.g. at http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bzip2/ ):

```
 You  can  also  compress  or decompress files to the standard output by
   giving the -c flag.
```

So, in the part before the `|`, you're looking for this:

```
bunzip2 -c SOB-MySQL-backup-summaries_live-2012-01-05.sql.bz2 | ...etc...
```